# Form label and form input in separate components

Tags: angular

I have a form label in one component and its associated reusable custom input in a separate component. I have designed it like this because sometimes I want a label with the custom input and sometimes I don't. Sometimes I want the label to be above the custom input and sometimes I want it inline with the custom input. Thus separate components makes sense. It looks something like this (although the markup in the parent component may vary):

component1.component.html:

```
<label for="myInput">Label Text</label>
<app-component2></app-component2>
```

component2.component.html

```
<input id="myInput" ... loads of custom stuff here>
```

The only problem is that the `label for` and `input id` does not work. When I click the label it does not select the input when the input is in another component. How can I make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap up both the components into a parent component and can pass the required id by emitting a event by   on click of the label into the

Your code will be like

Parentcomponent.html

```
<parentComponent>
<component1 (emitId) ='setLabelId($event)'></component1>
<component2 [labelId]='labelId'></component2>
</parentComponent>
```

and parentComponent.ts will be

```
 export class parentComponent implements OnInit {
 const labelId : string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  setLabelId(id:string){
  this.labelId = id;
  }

  }
```

and component1.ts will be like

```
 export class Component1 implements OnInit {
 @Output() emitId = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

handleLabelClick(id:string){
this.emitId.emit(id);
}

}
```

component1.html

```
<label onClick="handleLabelClick(myInput)" for="myInput">
```

where component2.ts will be like

```
 export class Component2 implements OnInit {
 @Input() labelId:string

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.labelId holds the value of required id
  }

}
```

and component2.html

```
<input id="myInput" ... loads of custom stuff here>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by doing this:

```
<label>
  <span>Label Text</span>
  <app-component2></app-component2>
</label>
```

where app-component2 contains the input element.

Answer (score 1):

You can relay the id attribute by reading the id as an `@Input`, rendering it to the form element in the template, and then removing it from the host element (as html ids need to be unique) once the template is initiated.

```
export class Component2 implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() id: string;

  constructor(
    private readonly _elementRef: ElementRef,
    private readonly _renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    // or rewrite it to another non-unique attribute
    this._renderer.removeAttribute(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'id');
  }
}
```

And in the Component2 template

```
<input id="{{id}}">
```

This allows Component1 to use the selector of Component2 as if it was an input element.

```
<label for="myInput">Label Text</label>
<app-component2 id="myInput"></app-component2>
```